# "Ghosts from the past" or "Ghosts of the past"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The text below is the translation of a text in Portuguese into English with the help of Google Translate:

You're still too young to be so discouraged. Don't let **ghosts from the past** make you lose faith in love. Sooner or later you will find the right person to make you happy.

Alternatively, Google gives the option of using the translated text as "Don't let **ghosts of the past** make you lose faith in love", that is, using the expression "ghosts of the past" instead of "ghosts from the past ".

Do both options have the same meaning?